# Error en manifest tras actualizar

Tags: android-manifest

Llevaba un tiempo con esto aparcado y el otro dia decidi continuar con el proyecto. lo abro me pide actualizar actualizo todo y al compilar me da el siguiente error.
He probado a crear un proyecto nuevo a ver si podia mirar todas las classes pero al implementar firestore y auth ya me empiezan a dar problemas tambien.
el tema es que estoy bloqueado y no se donde mirar

```
ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-36:19 to override.
```

añado la linea que indica en el manifest pero me sigue dando errores. 
tanto por una actualizacion?

el manifest lo tengo asi

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="bg.adrian.leaderboard">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/meeplecorona"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/meeplecorona"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".ConfigGrupo"/>
        <activity android:name=".MenuRegistro" />
        <activity android:name=".MenuRegistro_lista" />
        <activity android:name=".CrearRegistro" />
        <activity android:name=".MenuJugadores" />
        <activity android:name=".MenuJuegos" />
        <activity android:name=".CrearJuego" />
        <activity android:name=".MenuRankingJuegoLista" />
        <activity android:name=".EditorJuego" />
        <activity android:name=".ConfigUsuario" />
        <activity android:name=".MenuPrincipal">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MenuGrupos" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

esto es el gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bg.adrian.leaderboard"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'

    implementation 'petrov.kristiyan:colorpicker-library:1.1.4'
}
```

Comment: vale parece que en principio se ha solucionado. he copiado las versiones de los ficheros de otro proyecto que no habia actualizado y ya no da los errores. 
en cuestion en el Build.gradle module app he dejado estas versiones
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.2.0'
y en build.gradle proyect he dejado esta version de dependencias
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'